# How can I implement a Session Variable in Acumatica?

Tags: acumatica

I have a processing page in Acumatica that performs a Validation.  When we run this process, then switch to another record to perform the process again, we don't want to rerun Validation every time.  So, I need something outside of the scope of the BLC (like a flag) that I can set and will keep set until the Session or Page expires.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `PXContext.Session.SetString(key, value);` to set string value in the session. And `PXContext.Session[key]` to retrieve value.