# Is it possible to send parameter in PXSelector when clicking the Edit icon?

Tags: acumatica

I have a PXSelector which shows a list of payors. I added the AllowEdit=true parameter in order to be able to add a new one. However, I need to be able to send a patientID that would be retrieved from a field on the first form to the window in order for the customized form to work. Would I be able to override the function that calls the page and if so, what would it be called?

Comment: Which form and which control you try to extend?

Comment: The form I am trying to extend is a customized form of SO301000 and the control is <px:PXSelector ID="edCustPaymentID" runat="server" DataField="UsrPayorCaseID" AutoRefresh="True" AllowEdit="true" DataSourceID="ds" CommitChanges="True" AllowAddNew="true" >
            </px:PXSelector>

Answer (score 0):

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28865736/how-can-i-implement-a-session-variable-in-acumatica) may not be an exact answer for your question, but i think this might help you.

"You can use PXContext.Session.SetString(key, value); to set string value in the session. And PXContext.Session[key] to retrieve value."